# smartgwt - make window background transparent / no color

Tags: java, windows, smartgwt

we've tried to make the background of a smartgwt window transparent with no success :/ setting a transparent image as backgroundimage yields nor directly setting a custom style class with a transparent background setting yields no success.

is there any possibility to change the default background color : #ffffff or rgb(255,255,255) to transparent?

thank you in advance,
dave

Answer (score 1):

I think `#setOpacity(int)` should do the trick... Also see `#setDragOpacity(int)`.

Comment: Thank your for the answer, but `setOpacity(int opacity)` sets the overall opacity, eventually resulting in transparent members.

Answer (score 0):

I think I read that this would be a feature of the new Java JDK 7.  So if you can't find an answer that might be the problem. I'm not positive though.
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution in [Showcase] - [Forms] - [Custom Picker] (SmartGWT 2.2):

Try to use code like this:

```
    dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.setIsModal(true);  
    dialog.setShowModalMask(true);
    dialog.setShowHeader(false);  
    dialog.setShowEdges(false);
    dialog.setEdgeSize(10);
    dialog.setWidth(980);
    dialog.setHeight(700);  
    dialog.setShowToolbar(false);
    dialog.centerInPage();
```

I think this line disables background - setShowEdges(false).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `#setBackgroundColor("transparent")` ?

E.g.:

```
Window window = new Window();
window.setBackgroundColor("transparent");
```

Worked for me...